# Removing Drop-in Sink Mounting Clips

Tags: kitchens, sink, removal

I'm attempting to replace an old kitchen sink with a same-size drop in sink, but I'm having trouble removing the old sink clips.

Some of them were accessible so I just unscrewed them as expected, but others are not so accessible.

Any tips on how I might remove these? Maybe a specific tool I should use? *No need to preserve them for future use.*

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The proverbial rock and a hard place.

Answer (score 1):

I would say remove the triangle braces, an oscillating saw would work well ([this is the one i own](https://www.lowes.com/pd/DEWALT-20-Volt-MAX-Cordless-Brushless-Variable-Speed-Oscillating-Multi-Tool-Kit/1001008764)) or break them out with Channel lock (*adjustable*) pliers. I suppose you could drill a hole through them as well so you can get a screwdriver on them.
You can glue them back in after the new sink is in.

For the middle one you may be able to get a screwdriver in behind it and manipulate it out enough to get another screwdriver on it. Or cut away a notch to access the head.